# Java Android Webview Open File Chooser

Tags: java, android

So since now the *openFileChooser* does not work:

Is there any way to upload files from *webview* **or**
Any other ALTERNATIVE solutions **?**

Like how do we send a *file* or a image through *webview* to our site ?

Comment: I do this: bind a native jsinterface. add a click listener on the file upload button. on click, call the native to handle the file choosing, pass it back to the js (at this point change the type to be able to change its content), then intercept the request (need to be a GET for that), then handle the post yourself. quite a heavy solution, and not fully satisfactory as the input does not look entirely like it should after the type is changed.

Comment: So since now the openFileChooser does not work:? where is that documented?